# How to fix the regex for the validating email for the input using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

i want to check if the email entered by user is valid or not on the input field. and when the email is wrong disable the add button. if email is valid then enable the add button.

below is my code,

```
function Parent () {
    const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = React.useState(true);
    const onEmailChange = (event: any) => {
        setEmail(event.target.value);
    };
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const isValid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/.test(email); //this considers ab.ab@mail.com as invalid
        setIsDisabled(!isValid);
    }, [email];

    return (
        <Input
          type="text"
          value={email}
          onChange={onEmailChange}
          placeholder="Insert email"
        />
        <button
            disabled={isDisabled}
        >add</button>
    );
}
```

this works fine. but when user enters email "abc.ab@email.com" this is validated is a wrong. could someone help me fix the regex to accept this too. thanks.

Comment: [https://emailregex.com/](https://emailregex.com/)

Comment: this is the RegEx, which I use for Email `/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/`

Hope that helps

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)